# Docker Swarm Containers Inaccessible

Tags: docker, docker-compose, docker-swarm

I'm trying to deploy an application using docker swarm on a DigitalOcean Droplet. It should be pretty straight forward, but I'm unable to access the containers that spawn from the service and they always end up shutting down. I haven't found any logs that help besides `unhealthy container shutdown failed: error while removing network: unknown network shypn_default id aofrasysl66hoqz6k8o8jlhlu`

Here's my docker-compose.yml:

```
version: '3.7'

services:
  nodejs:
    image: solvewithtech/shypnbackend
    env_file:
      - .env
    ports:
      - '3000:3000'
    deploy:
      mode: replicated
      replicas: 2
      update_config:
        order: start-first
        failure_action: rollback
        delay: 10s
    healthcheck:
      test: ["CMD", "curl", "-f", "http://localhost:3000 || exit 1"]
```

I started on a new Ubuntu 22.10 x64 build, then ran `docker swarm init --advertise-addr <public ip address>` After that, I logged in to docker, and ran `docker stack deploy -c docker-compose.yml app --with-registry-auth` The containers are created as they should be, but they're inaccessible which causes the healthcheck to fail. Any ideas on what's causing this? The image runs perfectly when just running with `docker run`

This is the guide I followed too:
https://medium.com/@limone.eth/deploy-docker-containers-with-zero-downtime-ed06b0a0966d

Comment: Not sure about Digital Ocean, but when building a Docker swarm, the --advertise-addr should probably be the private address that you open a bunch of sensitive firewall on: 2377, 4789 etc to allow overlay networking, gossip and docker swarm management calls to happen.